# Characterizing Isbell self-dual objects

Tags: ct.category-theory

It is well known that under the Isbell duality $\text{Spec}\dashv {\cal O} : {\cal V}^{A^°} \leftrightarrows \big({\cal V}^A\big)^°$ representable functors are self-dual, i.e. fixed by the unit and counit of the adjunction: $$\text{Spec}({\cal O}(\hom(-,x)))\cong \hom(-,x)\qquad\qquad {\cal O}(\text{Spec}(\hom(y,-)))\cong \hom(y,-)$$

No mention is made about representables being the *unique* self-dual objects. Is it true?

If not, how to characterize a bigger class of Isbell self-dual objects? My initial guess was that at least a class of colimits of representables are Isbell-self-dual. They are not, even for coproducts, if this computation is correct:

1. ${\cal O}(\hom(-,x)\amalg \hom(-,y)) = \hom(x,-)\times \hom(y,-)$;
2. $\text{Spec}$ of this evaluated in $a$ now equals
   $$
   Nat(\hom(-,x)\times \hom(y,-), \hom(a,-))
   $$
   that doesn't seem related to the initial presheaf. If you assume that $A$ has coproducts, in fact, it is true that this is $\hom(a,x\amalg y)$, so that $\text{Spec}({\cal O}(h_x\amalg h_y)) \cong h_{x\amalg y}$, different from $h_y\amalg h_y$ in general.

This question has already been [asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1953264/examples-of-isbell-self-dual-objects) on math.SE, and it was me that pointed the OP to another MO thread discussing the topic, but I'm seeking some explicit answer now.

Comment: One very obvious type of counterexample is where $A$ is not Cauchy complete, since the presheaf and copresheaf categories for $A$ and its Cauchy completion coincide. A keyphrase btw is "Isbell envelope" aka "Isbell completion".

Comment: So in such a case there are non-representable self-dual objects? And what are they?

Comment: Maybe I see your point, looking at the $n$Lab page of Cauchy completion: if $A$ is not Cauchy complete there are profunctors $* \to A$ that admit a right adjoint in $\bf Prof$ without being functors. This, however, does not answer to the question how to find one of such profunctor and how/why it is Isbell self-dual. But maybe I'm not seeing the obvious? Thanks!

Comment: Fosco, all I was saying in the first sentence is that if $\bar{A}$ denotes the Cauchy completion and $a \in Ob(\bar{A})$, then the representable $\bar{A}(-, a)$ is a fixed point of the Isbell conjugation between $\mathcal{V}^{\bar{A}}$ and $\mathcal{V}^{\bar{A}^{op}}$, which coincides with the Isbell conjugation between $\mathcal{V}^A$ and $\mathcal{V}^{A^{op}}$. If $a$ is not already an object of $A$, then this gives an example of a non-$A$ representable that is a fixed point.

Comment: So, are Isbell self-dual objects for $A$ all and the only representables of the Cauchy completion $\bar A$?

Comment: Fosco, no -- my original comment was just a cheap observation. I've just posted an answer which says more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick answer for now, which I might add more to later. Recall that for every adjunction $F \dashv G: C \to D$ there is the notion of "fixed point" of the adjunction which has two faces: either it is an object $c$ of $C$ for which the counit $\epsilon_c: FGc \to c$ is an isomorphism, or it is an object $d$ of $D$ for which the unit $\eta_d: d \to GFd$. The adjunction $F \dashv G$ then induces an adjoint equivalence between the full subcategories $\text{Fix}_{FG}(C)$ and $\text{Fix}_{GF}(D)$, and thus we identify these categories. In the case of the Isbell conjugation adjunction for a small category $X$, the category of fixed points is often called the *Isbell envelope* or *Isbell completion*; let's denote it $I(C)$.

In the special case where $C$ is a preorder, i.e., a $\mathbf{2}$-enriched category, $I(C)$ is a preorder which goes by a more famous name: the Dedekind-MacNeille completion. You can find some discussion of this in the MO-answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/59295/2926). In this case $I(C)$ *is* both complete and cocomplete (i.e. admits small limits and colimits).

In other cases, the Isbell completion need not be $\mathcal{V}$-complete/cocomplete, as you correctly surmise (see comments below the MO-answer I just mentioned), but it can be quite a bit larger (and certainly larger than the Cauchy completion). It's maybe best to point to some examples. For the case where $\mathcal{V}$ is the monoidal closed category $([0, \infty), \geq, +)$, i.e., where $\mathcal{V}$-categories are metric spaces in the sense of Lawvere, Simon Willerton has an interesting article which connects the Isbell completion to the tight span of metric spaces; you can find a Café discussion [here](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2013/01/tight_spans_isbell_completions.html) where some examples are computed.

Isbell completions also figure in "[comparative smootheology](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0802.2225v2.pdf)", but I'd need to study and think more before commenting on that. You can also find more references to the Isbell completion in the nLab; as I said, I may come back and add more.

Comment: "I may come back and add more" you already helped a lot, but please come back!

Comment: I have an additional question, is $A\mapsto \text{Spec}_A \dashv {\cal O}_A$ a functor from $Cat$ to the category $Adj$ of adjunctions?

Comment: Maybe it depends what is meant by $Adj$ (a bicategory), and it may depend on which functor you mean. If morphisms in $Adj$ are pairs of functors which commute with both the left and right adjoint parts, then one thing to look at is a functor $Cat^{op} \to Adj$ that takes $f: A \to B$ to the pair $(V^{f^{op}}, (V^f)^{op})$, but a calculation shows this doesn't work. I didn't check, but I'm skeptical that other possibilities involving left or right adjoints to $V^{f^{op}}$ and $(V^f)^{op}$ work either.

Comment: By the way, there's one fact of life which is either disconcerting or interesting depending on your point of view, given by the saying "Injective Hulls are not natural", a title of a paper by Adamek, Herrlich, and Rosicky. An example is the MacNeille completion of a poset, which is a special case of the Isbell completion/envelope. So if you're hoping that Isbell completions are cleanly functorial, you're probably in for a disappointment. :-(  I've been burned by this type of hope in the past.

Comment: Argh! So $\lnot$"everything is a functor"? That's something I must remember next time I brag about the good old saying. Let's say that I want to know if, in any sense whatsoever, sending a category to "its" Isbell adjunction is functorial.