# What is the relationship between free bicompletion and the Isbell envelope?

Tags: ct.category-theory, monads, 2-categories, completion, universal-property

Given a small category $\mathbb C$, we can form the free cocompletion $\mathbf y : \mathbb C \to \mathcal P(\mathbb C)$ and the free completion $\mathbf y^\circ : \mathbb C \to \mathcal P^\circ(\mathbb C)$. These constructions factor through two others:

1. The [free bicompletion](https://mr.math.ca/article/free-bicomplete-categories/) $\mathbf b : \mathbb C \to \mathcal B(\mathbb C)$.
2. The [Isbell envelope](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Isbell+envelope) $\mathbf i :\mathbb C \to \mathcal I(\mathbb C)$.

[image: free bicompletion and Isbell envelope]

Both constructions have universal properties: the former freely adds limits and colimits; whilst the latter freely constructs a [cylinder factorisation system](https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.7108).

However, it is not clear to me exactly how the two relate. May one construction be expressed in terms of the other (e.g. is there a factorisation of free bicompletion through the Isbell envelope)? If not, is there some other relationship?

Comment: I'd like to know ! When $\mathbb{C}$ is small the Isbell completion is complete and cocomplete correct ? So we always have a limite & colimit preserving functor $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{C}) \to \mathcal{I}(\mathbb{C})$. Do you know if this functor has right and left adjoints ? I suspect not, but that's the only way I can think to send the Isbell completion to the Bi-completion.

Comment: My understanding is that it is bicomplete (which follows from the definition of CFS). However, I should note that there is an issue with terminology, in that you'll find it stated (e.g. in [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/260342)) that the Isbell envelope may not have small limits or colimits: but this instead refers to the construction arising from the Isbell adjunction (the distinction is [discussed here](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2014/08/wrestling_with_tight_spans.html#c047005)). I don't know whether the functor you mention has adjoints, either.